Blazor SSR Enhance EditForm in NavMenu.razor
I have a blazor ssr project with many EditForm that are work correctly in all pages except NavMenu.razor component. One of these EditForm of pages for example is :
<EditForm Model="vm" OnValidSubmit="Submit" FormName="IndustryAddEdit" Enhance>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputText autofocus @bind-Value="vm.Title" class="form-control" placeholder />
        <label>Title</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => vm.Title" class="text-danger" />
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <SubmitBtn />
    </div>

</EditForm>

But when I add an EditForm like top sample EditForm to NavMenu.razor I get this error :
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter, please provide one of these.

The only way I can resolve this error is remove Enhance and Model="vm" then add EditContext="editContext" to the EditForm then use this OnInitialized() method :
<EditForm OnSubmit="Submit" FormName="SearchForm" EditContext="editContext">

[SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "SearchForm")] 
public SearchVm vm { get; set; } = new();

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    vm ??= new();
    editContext = new(vm);
}

But these changes work without Enhanced Navigation and cause to refresh the browser when form posted to the server, how to add an EditForm to NavMenu.razor with Enhanced Navigation. I use this form for search on NavMenu.
When I use <EditForm Model="vm" OnSubmit="Submit" FormName="SearchForm" Enhance> in NavMenu.razor submit method do not  execute and browser console show this error in console : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')
at HTMLDocument.Pi (blazor.web.js:1:174517)


It works. I cannot reproduce, could you share the the "@code{... }"

NavMenu.razor :



<InputText @bind-Value="vm!.SearchText" name="vm.SearchText" class="form-control mt-3" placeholder />
Search Commodity



C# : public void Submit(EditContext editContext)
{
if (vm!.SearchText!.IsEmpty() == false)
NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"Search/{vm!.SearchText}", forceLoad: false, replace: true);
}


How is the "vm" model defined?

[SupplyParameterFromForm]
public SearchVm? vm { get; set; }

class :
public class SearchVm
{
public string? SearchText { get; set; }
}


Why not simply make it like [SupplyParameterFromForm] public SearchVm? vm { get; set; } = new ();

I tested [SupplyParameterFromForm] public SearchVm? vm { get; set; } = new (); the "EditForm requires either a Model parameter, or an EditContext parameter" resolved, but still submit not occur and show this error in browser console : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')
at HTMLDocument.Pi (blazor.web.js:1:174517)"
